# Storm Ui error kafka spout, not using HDP

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I Have Storm 1.1.1 installed on my machine and on my other machine I'm using Kafka version 0.10.0.1. Both services are connected with Zookeeper version 3.4.6

I succesfully deployed my topology, that looked like this:

```java
public class SOTopology  {
    public static void main (String[] args ) throws Exception {
        final String brokers = args[0];
        final String kafkaTopic = args[1];
        final String mongo_uri = args[2];
        final String mongo_collection = args[3];
    
        TopologyBuilder topology = new TopologyBuilder();
        topology.setSpout("KafkaSpout",new KafkaSpout<>(KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(brokers, kafkaTopic).build()), 1);
        topology.setBolt("FilterBolt", new Filterbolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("KafkaSpout");
        topology.setBolt("TagCountBolt", new TagCountBolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("FilterBolt");
        topology.setBolt("TopicBolt", new TopicBolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("FilterBolt");
        topology.setBolt("MongoDBBolt",new MongoDBBolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("TagCountBolt").shuffleGrouping("TopicBolt");

        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(true);
        conf.put("mongo.uri", mongo_uri);
        conf.put("mongo.collection", mongo_collection);
        conf.setMaxSpoutPending(40);
        conf.setNumWorkers(10);
        conf.setDebug(true);

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("StackOverflowTopology", conf, topology.createTopology());
    }
}
```

When I go to my StormUI I get the following message `Offset lags for kafka not supported for older versions. Please update kafka spout to latest version.` I am not using HDP but I'm already using the latest storm version and my storm-clients.jar and storm-kafka-client.jar are both for version 1.1.1. Anyone Who has an idea how I can fix this?

EDIT:  In the possible duplicate they are using HDP and they fixed it by just updating their HDP cluster. Since I'm not running it on HDP, I can't really update my HDP cluster and I'm certain that my storm is the right version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storm UI throwing "Offset lags for kafka not supported for older versions. Please update kafka spout to latest version."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932441/storm-ui-throwing-offset-lags-for-kafka-not-supported-for-older-versions-pleas)

Comment: @vatsalmevada in the possible duplicate they are using HDP and they fixed it by just updating their HDP cluster. Since I'm not running it on HDP, I can't really update my HDP cluster and I'm certain that my storm is the right version.

Comment: Are you also certain that you don't have multiple jars (of different versions possibility added as part of dependencies of other libraries) for storm-clients and storm-kafka-client?

Comment: Yes I double checked it multiple times to make sure that I'm only using the required Jars with the right version. I'm importing the following `KafkaSpout,
 KafkaSpotConfig` from `org.apache.storm.kafka.spout` that I'm getting from the `storm-kafka-client-1.1.1.jar` and there is no other version there

Comment: @SebastienPattyn I'm having the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ale93p No unfortunately not. I was Using ActiveMQ instead of Kafka to test and then It wasn't working as well. So the issue will probably not be with the kafkaspout but with the topology itself or with Storm.

Comment: @SebastienPattyn I gave a look around the logs, apparently the UI still use the old java class `org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout` instead of using the new APIs `org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout`, so when it tries to connect to the KafkaSpout it gets an error, to solve this I just did a rollback to an older version of kafka (0.8.2.2) and using the old storm kafka APIs in my java code, now it seems to work.

Comment: @ale93p the problem I have is that I really have to use version 0.10.1 for this case. Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the linked question: The solution is upgrading to a recent version of the platform.

In case you for some reason manage to avoid the distribution this was perhaps not possible/practical at time of asking the question but as we are several years later now it certainly is the case that you can upgrade. (And probably already have).